# I have JavaScript issues in my project when I upload to server

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, https

It works in the local system but, when I upload it to the server there are some problems.

I used the same code:

https://smmsky.co/

http://http://blaci.info/

1st is working well but, the 2nd is not.

I want to know this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error when trying to access that second site, as it is indicating its an IP address to domain name issue, meaning its highly likely a server configuration issue or a DNS name not being registered issue or a firewall block on the server or port(s) 80 and/or 443 are not opened properly for accessing files. In other words its probably something with the server's configuration. "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".
Here's a link maybe more insight. https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-err-name-not-resolved-error/